# Pretty print a table in C++

Tags: c++, pretty-print

I am looking for a library similar to prettytable but in C++

http://code.google.com/p/prettytable/

I know how to generate one myself using either printf or iostream. However, I would like to know if there is a library for this.

I am interested only in writing this ASCII table to the console.

Preferably something like:

```
std::vector<std::string> headers;
headers.push_back("My Awesome Header 1");
headers.push_back("My Awesome Header 2");
headers.push_back("My Awesome Header 3");


PrettyTablePrinter ptp;
ptp.SetHeaders(headers);
// Set some other options here
ptp.AddRow(data[0]);
ptp.AddRow(data[1]);
ptp.AddRow(data[2]);

ptp.Print(&std::cout);
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950639/printing-2d-table-headers/2950851#2950851

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Since I have not found a good C++ solution, I have written one for you all

https://github.com/dattanchu/bprinter/wiki

Answer (score 15):

I wasn't satisfied with any of the ones I found online so I wrote my own: https://github.com/friedmud/variadic_table

It uses variadic templates to allow each column to hold a different type.  It also only requires C++11.

```
VariadicTable<std::string, double, int, std::string> vt({"Name", "Weight", "Age", "Brother"});

vt.addRow({"Cody", 180.2, 40, "John"});
vt.addRow({"David", 175.3, 38, "Andrew"});
vt.addRow({"Robert", 140.3, 27, "Fande"});

vt.print();
```

This will output:

```
--------------------------------------
| Name |  Weight  |    Age   |Brother|
--------------------------------------
|Cody  |     180.2|        40|John   |
|David |     175.3|        38|Andrew |
|Robert|     140.3|        27|Fande  |
--------------------------------------
```

This is actively being used in a large software project - so it will be maintained and developed over time.  Feel free to submit issues / PRs

Comment: The repository once cloned have 20+ errors just when I run make.

Comment: it's also header only!

Comment: Nice that it's header only, but the GNU licence is a bummer for non-private use :(

Answer (score 9):

To my knowledge, you have three major options here :

- A "C way" through the use of [`printf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) with width specifiers
- A "C++ way" through the use of [stream manipulators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/) (in particular [`std::setw`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setw/) and [`std::setfill`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setfill/))
- An intermediate way using [Boost.Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/format/index.html) which allow you to use `printf` style formatters with streams.

I'm not aware of any library which could help you in the "table design" more than this.

Answer (score 5):

While not exactly what you're looking for, [Boost.Spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/home/) contains a library (named Karma) usable to generate this kind of output fairly easily. The docs are [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/karma.html).

Answer (score 4):

**LibFort**

It's *Fantastic*, they have Several *cool table styles* too.

https://github.com/seleznevae/libfort

Comment: Could not get this to work with Visual Studio / Windows.  Yes, I ran CMAKE, but encountered lots of compile errors.

Answer (score 4):

#### In my opinion, these 2 libraries are the best options today :-

1. [tabulate](https://github.com/p-ranav/tabulate)
2. [libfort](https://github.com/seleznevae/libfort)

libfort is comparatively simpler and smaller since it's written in C, whereas tabulate is highly customisable and is written in C++

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I just wanted a simple library and *libfort* provided everything I needed, excellent library.

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve it using [ncurses](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) library. Its C library.

Answer (score -3):

The most generic way to format any output of all, in fact the *only* way to do so within the C++ language is with I/O Manipulators.
http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/io/omanipulators.html