# Displaying a table in C using printf/cprintf?

Tags: c

I have to display a table in C using printf/cprintf, particularly this table.

[image]

The data should be given by an user (number/name/age/wage).

Is there any smart way to create such a table, not using a ton of printfs/cprintfs? (I don't even know the difference, I didn't find anything about cprintfs' syntax and usage on cplusplus.com or anywhere)

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I didn't try anything yet because I really don't want to waste a lot of time writing a ton of functions when there might be an easier way that I don't know about. I'm thinking about creating a function for displaying a plain line (only with dashes), one for displaying the first line of the header, one for the second, and one for each line containing text. But I feel like this is too much and there might be an easier way.

Comment: You can try find or translate library like answer in this problem ```https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471714/pretty-print-a-table-in-c```
But in the end there is no other way 

I recomend to learn a lot about printf strings to have yours windows always the same size

Comment: `printf("%<HERE>d|%<HERE>s|...", id, name, ...)` see what you can replace `<HERE>` with

Comment: The difference between `printf()` and Microsoft's `cprintf()` is the first goes to `stdout` and the second goes to console, and cannot be redirected. Apart from that, it behaves like the `Xprintf()` function family.

Comment: As @pmg suggested, find out how to use the [`width`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions) specifiers. You can use a variable argument to control the width, or hard-coded value.

Comment: I'm going to look into width specifiers. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Only a suggestion (this is an example - not a fully functional code):
Determine the different kind of lines you want to print - for example static lines, which do not have data and lines which contain data. From the example above you only have two different dynamic lines (those with data). The rest are static data.
Create a bunch of constant string definitions, which are used for format strings for the
printf. Gave those constants reasonable name like 'fullBar' 'header_a' 'header_b' and such. Now you can use those in commands like:

```
printf( full_bar );
printf( header_a );
printf( header_b );
printf( data_row, number, name, age, wage );
```

and so on.
Knowing about the format strings, printf and friends is essential for successfully programming C.

Comment: How can I create a "constant string definition", if you don't mind?

Answer (score 1):

`cprintf` is a Windows-specific command for colored text

`printf` is the posix method, but immediately writes to output

What I would recommend is building your strings via `sprintf` which stores what's to be printed to an intermediary string, that way, as your strings grow, your vertical spacers stay formatted. The return from `sprintf` (and `printf`) just so happen to be the number of characters written to your buffer.

Here's a really basic example of how you could create a variable length bar on top.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct person{
    int id;
    char first_name[100];
    char last_name[100];
    int age;
    int salary;
};

int num_char(person * p, char * buf){
    return sprintf(buf,"|%d|%s,%s|%d|%d|",p->id,p->last_name,p->first_name,p->age,p->salary);
}

int print_bar(int n){
    char temp[400];
    char * ptr = temp;
    for (;n--;){
        sprintf(ptr++,"-");
    }
    printf("%s\n",temp);
}

int main(){
    person uut1 = {1,"John","Smith",40,31000};
    char temp[400];
    int res = num_char(&uut1, temp);
    print_bar(res);
    printf("%s",temp);
    printf("\n");
    print_bar(res);
}
```

You'd need to do some more work to format for multiple people, but I leave that as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and ideas.