# C++: reading output from from txt file problem

Tags: c++

I am making a simple record system in C++ where inputs will be saved on txt file. I already have a code on reading the data from txt file but it display like this:

```
  Name  |  Address  |  Temperature  |  Date  |  Time  |  Note
=============================================================
      Drerw   rwer   43   23   3   f
dsadd
      jdshk   37   09-02-20   9   N
Drerw   rwer
      43   23   3   f
Drerw   rwer   43
      23   3   f
Drerw   rwer   43   23
      3   f
```

The problem is the second and rest of the data is printed with spaces. I want the output to be like the first line. I don't know where the problem is.

Here is my code:

```
void displayRecord() {
    system("CLS");
    cout << "===== Current Record(s) =====" << endl;
    cout << "=============================" << endl;

    int counter = 0;
    cout
            << "  Name  |  Address  |  Temperature  |  Date  |  Time  |  Note  " << endl;
    cout << "=======================================================================" << endl;

    for (int x = 0; x < maxRow; x++) {
        if (visitorName[x] != "\0") {
            counter++;
            cout << "   " << "   " << visitorName[x] << "   "
                    << visitorAddress[x] << "   " << visitorTemp[x] << "   "
                    << visitorDate[x] << "   " << visitorTime[x] << "   "
                    << visitorNote[x] << endl;
        }
    }
    if (counter == 0) {
        cout << "No Record Found!" << endl;
    }
}


void openFile() {
    string line;
    ifstream myfile(
            "C:\\Users\\darwi\\eclipse-workspace\\C++\\EstablishmentContactTracing\\db.txt");

    int x = 0; 
        if (!myfile) {
            cout << "Unable to Open File!";
        }
        while (myfile) {
                getline(myfile, visitorName[x], ',');
                getline(myfile, visitorAddress[x], ',');
                getline(myfile, visitorTemp[x], ',');
                getline(myfile, visitorDate[x], ',');
                getline(myfile, visitorTime[x], ',');
                getline(myfile, visitorNote[x], ',');
                x++;
        }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use `std:getline()` and parse the input. It really helps.

Comment: this may help also. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471714/pretty-print-a-table-in-c/5696788

Comment: You'll be glad to hear you don't need anyone's help to figure this out, just a tool you already have: your debugger! This is exactly what a debugger is for. It runs your program, one line at a time, and shows you what's happening. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all problems in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help. Have you tried using your debugger, already? If not, why not? What did your debugger show you?

Comment: You're printing spaces between the items so it's not surprising that the items are space separated? Just change the spaces to pipe characters?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, removing endl solve my problem.